# My Ubuntu 12.10 partition is frozen in the Safe Graphics Mode?

Tags: 12.10, live-usb, fan

I have an Acer Aspire 5315 with Ubuntu 12.10 on it. I had it fully customized, except for the fact that my cooling fan wouldn't work. After some research, I found out that the fans are run off of SOFTWARE. That only works with VISTA. SO, I did a system edit of some sort, and my fan started working! Sadly, the next day, it stopped. After more research, I decided to update my BIOS. Then, I booted it back up, and it said,

```
"The system is running in low-graphics mode

Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself."
```

And it's STUCK in this mode. I can press "enter" and it brings up another screen, with multiple options. The kicker is, it won't let me choose ANY of them. I have no pointer, and when I try to engage in the command prompt with "ALT+CTRL+F1" it only shows up with a bunch of blue lines.

Please help me! All my friends say that it's the wrong driver configuration.

I have no idea what to do.

I am currently posting this from my Linux Nadia Live CD.

Comment: Did you try any of the answers to this ["How to fix 'the system is running in low graphics mode error'"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) question?

Comment: Yes, I have. None of the solutions there work. I am COMPLETELY frozen in my failsafex mode, and I think I'll just get rid of Ubuntu, and replace it with Mint. Goodbye, 8.5 GB's of important data.